# Will cassandra do multi partition search for compounded primary key

Tags: cassandra

I have a scenario, let's say below is my cassandra table

```
CREATE TABLE USER (
id TEXT,
name TEXT,
age int,
role TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY ((id, role), age));
```

Now I should be able to query user table using either `id` or `role` or both `id` and `role`. My question is when I use only `id` or `role` in the `WHERE` clause to find user, in this case will cassandra search for user record in different partition(and nodes)? As I am not searching user using both `id` and `role` which make the PK of my table.

Answer (score 1):

When you use a compound partition key like in your example `PRIMARY KEY ((id, role), age)`

Cassandra will concatenate the two values together. It's a technique used to create a more unique or sometimes granular partition key to better control how evenly data gets distributed around the respective datacenter.

Because id and role are concatenated then hashed, you must always provide both the id AND role. Cassandra will not know what to do if you give only part of the compound partition key.